# Convert Rows into column without using Pivot

Tags: sql, database

I have a data set, but the sample data will look like the below one:

```
 Country Date       Category   X    Y
 IN     2011-11-22  B          1    0
 BA     2010-11-23  B         11    0.2
 IN     2011-11-22  A          1    0
 BA     2011-11-23  A          1    1
 IN     2011-07-28  A          1    0
```

want to convert it into : Output

```
 Country Date       B_X    B_Y  A_X  A_Y
 IN     2011-11-22  1       0    1    0
 BA     2010-11-23  11      0.2  1    1
 IN     2011-07-28  0       0    1    0
```

I have tried using case but it is not giving me a desired output, can anyone help!!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? You have tagged both...

Comment: Please show the query you are using and explain the logic for combining rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just want to aggregate by `country`/`date` and use conditional aggregation:

```
select country, date,
       sum(case when category = 'B' then x end) as x_b,
       sum(case when category = 'B' then y end) as y_b,
       sum(case when category = 'A' then x end) as x_a,
       sum(case when category = 'A' then y end) as y_a
from t
group by country, date;
```